Vercel deployment and google Authorized redirect URIs
After deploying with vercel i get a link to follow https://nameofproject-projects.vercel.app/auth/callback and authenticate. In Google Cloud Api i add this link as an authorized redirect URI and wait even some minutes. Then if i navigate to the link with the added "/auth" and got the Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch. Locally though is working flawless :/
const express = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const redirectUri = isProduction
  ? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/auth/callback`
  : "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback";

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  "Client ID",
  "Client Secret",
  redirectUri
);

let tokens;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
  const callbackUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/auth/callback`;
  const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
    redirect_uri: callbackUrl,
  });
  res.redirect(authUrl);
});

app.get("/auth/callback", async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;
  try {
    const { tokens: authTokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(authTokens);
    tokens = authTokens;
    console.log("Tokens:", tokens);
    res.send("Authentication successful! You can now close this tab.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during authentication:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Authentication failed");
  }
});


